# How to solve a system of nonlinear differential equations like this numerically

Tags: differential-equations, nonlinear

There are a set of nonlinear Bloch equations.  `ParametricNDSolve` can not give the correct answer, how to deal with these equations?

The desired answer should be (taken from Jiang et al., Sci. Adv. 2021; 7 : eabe0719)
[image]

```
γ = -1.18 10^7;
B0 = 750 10^(-9);
Bac = 10 10^(-9);
T10 = 1/0.05;
T20 = 1/0.05;
γse = 0.03;
PRb = 1;
νac = 1;


ωx[t_] := 0
ωy[t_] := 2 Pi γ χ Px[t]
ωz[t_] := 2 Pi γ (B0 + Bac Cos[2 Pi νac t])
sol1 = ParametricNDSolve[{Px'[t] == 
    Py[t] ωz[t] - Pz[t] ωy[t] - Px[t]/T20,
   Py'[t] == Pz[t] ωx[t] - Px[t] ωz[t] - Py[t]/T20,
   Pz'[t] == 
    Px[t] ωy[t] - Py[t] ωx[t] - 
     Pz[t]/T10 + γse (PRb - Pz[t]),
   Px[0] == 0, Py[0] == 10^(-1), Pz[0] == 0.5}, {Px, Py, Pz}, {t, 0, 
   200}, {χ}, Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", 
  MaxSteps -> Infinity];

Td = 1/5;
solchi = NSolve[
  1/Td == χ (γ γse)/(γse + 1/T10)
     PRb, χ];
data12 = ParallelTable[{t, ( Py[χ][t] /. sol1) /. 
     Flatten[solchi]}, {t, 0, 200, .001}];
ListPlot[data12(*,PlotRange\[Rule]All*)]
```

Comment: What's wrong about the answer `ParametricNDSolve` gives?

Comment: `\[Gamma]` is undefined.

Comment: Sorry,   `\[Gamma] = -1.18 10^7;` @MichaelE2

Comment: The result `ParametricNDSolve` given does not like the picture attached above. @ChrisK